# How to make the window selection wider?

Tags: unity, launcher

I would like to see more of the terminal window title when selecting from the Unity Launcher as my working directories may be quite long.

Is there a simple way to configure this?

[image]

Comment: If you hover over the shortened ones, do you get a tooltip showing the full path? I don't use Unity and so I'm asking.

Comment: No.  Just highlighting the line the mouse cursor hovers over.